# Bar chart writing count on the bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations, grouped-bar-chart

I am trying to write the counts on the bar using bar-plot from matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [
    ["index", "G1", "G2"],
    ["0", 98, 111],
    ["1", 1, 0]
]

# Extract the index and data for plotting
index = [row[0] for row in data[1:]]
G1 = [row[1] for row in data[1:]]
G2 = [row[2] for row in data[1:]]

# Create the bar chart
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar_width = 0.35
index = range(len(index))
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.bar(index, G1, bar_width, label='G1')
plt.bar([i + bar_width for i in index], G2, bar_width, label='G2')

# Set x-axis labels
plt.xlabel('Test')
plt.xticks([i + bar_width / 2 for i in index], index)

# Add values on top of the bars
for i in range(len(index)):
    plt.text(index[i], G1[i] + 100, str(G1[i]), ha='center')
    plt.text(index[i] + bar_width, G2[i] + 100, str(G2[i]), ha='center')

# Set labels and title
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.legend()

plt.show()

plt.clf()
plt.cla()
plt.close()
```

There are two charts generated, one is an empty graph

and, another graph is the actual plot where the text of the bar is goes out of the chart [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOWQI.png)

What is the issue, how to solve so that the count of the bar shows on top of the bar instead of printing out of the chart

Comment: `for c in plt.gca().containers: plt.bar_label(c, fmt='%.2f', label_type='edge')` or `for c in ax.containers: ax.bar_label(c, fmt='%.2f', label_type='edge')` [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSBNN.png)

Comment: Two charts are generated because you did `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, which creates the unused figure, and then you redundantly did `plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))`